# Recurrency problem Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, recursive-query, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working with EF 4.1 CTP5 and SQL Server 2008. I need to understand how to solve a recurrency problem. I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class Nation   
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<NationAlly> NationAllies {get;set;}
}

public class NationAlly
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int level {get;set;}
    public Nation Owner {get; set;}
    public Nation toNation {get;set;}
}
```

The entities are mapped to the database with two tables (Nations and NationAllies). Besides, there are two relationships. 1) From NationAllies.OwnerID to Nation.ID
2) From NationAllies.ToNationID to Nation.ID

When I try to retrieve an object of Nation type from my database, I access the DbContext class NationDB:

```
Nation selectedNation = ((nationDB.Nations.Include("NationAllies")).Where(m => m.name == "France")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is that I get a selectedNation object which has a list of NationAllies but every NationAlly in the list has the field toNation = null.
First of all I would like the field toNation to retrieve the correct information from the database. How do I do this?

Then of course toNation will be connected with other NationAllies which on their turn will have an other Nation. How could possibly a recursive map be built? My idea is to navigate the map until a certain level, by querying the database in a specific way. Doing so, what would be the best approach to have good speed performance?

Comment: How do you map these entities. First of all your code doesn't corespond with your query because `name` in `Nation` is integer. Also default mapping will point `toNation` back to parent entity which is in your case France. There will be no recursion.

Comment: 1) Corrected mistaken type in Nation.name 2) Added description on mapping

Comment: @Ladislav: you have recursion in sense that every Nation can have several NationAlly(s). Every NationAlly have one Nation in the toNation field, which, on his turn, can have several NationAlly. In this case, an entire hierarchical organization, or map, is created. The boundaries of the map can be of course finite (ending up with "leaves" who do not produce new branches, i.e. Nations without Allies) or infinite (Nations all interconnected with each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like NationAllies is junction table with additional properties. The problem is that EF doesn't eager load nested navigation properties if you do not specify them explicitly in `Include` method. If you want to have toNation filled you must use

```
nationDB.Nations.Include("NationAllies.toNation")
```

or

```
nationDB.Nations.Include(n => n.NationAllies.Select(na => na.toNation))
```

You can also enable lazy loading. Make all your navigation properties `virtual` (`toNation`, `NationOwner` and `NationAllies`) and unless you close the context all properties will be loaded once you first access them.

Comment: Fine. Problem solved by using approach #1. Approach #2 looks very interesting: if I understood right, the context will load in memory the objects when I will access them? It means that, i.e., the toNation property will automatically retrieve database values when I "navigate the map" to that property?

Comment: Yes it is lazy execution of select statement in database.